# Create a link on an external website using URL parameters?

Tags: lightning, url, weblinks

I have an application external to Salesforce where I want to embed a link with a URL parameter with the Customer ID, that will redirect to the Salesforce account page in a new window.

Something like this: https://ID.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/?={AccountID}

This seems like a really simple ask, but I have not been able to find anything related to creating links/URLs from OUTSIDE of Salesforce.

Comment: Is AccountId the 15- or 18-character Salesforce ID, or some other account ID? That would make a difference on how you'd want to go about your solution.

Comment: Not the Salesforce ID. In our case, the field is "Customer Number", which is unique to each customer.